# 2 dimension array processing in haskell

Tags: file, haskell

Sorry for my question which might seem trivial to some (I'm new). I have a file which contains a map looking like this :

```
---#--###----

-#---#----##-

------------@
```

In this file, `–` characters indicate that you are free to move in this direction. The `#` character indicates that you cannot move any further in this direction and you should go somewhere else. The `@` character indicates the location of the treasure. In this case, it is in the bottom right corner, but it could be anywhere in the map. So I have to go through these lines and see if I can reach the `@`. Here we are starting at the top left corner. So far I have managed to read the content of the file. And I'm wondering how to process this in Haskell. It will be easy in Java using a 2-dimensional array but how can I appproach this problem in Haskell?

For example, for the previous example, the path is:

```
+++#--###----

-#+--#----##-

--++++++++++@
```

The `+` symbol represents the path to the @ symbol.

This the algorithm I have to implement it in Java:

```
Dfs(i,j) {
  if (arr[i][j+1] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size) {
      Dfs(i,j+1) 
  } else if(arr[i][j+1] == "@") {

  }

  if (arr[i][j-1] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size) {
        Dfs(i,j-1) 
  }   else if(arr[i][j-1] == "@") {

  }

  if (arr[i+1][j] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size) {
      Dfs(i+1,j) 
  } else if(arr[i+1][j] == "@") {

  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking.  You can use [[Char]] or some nested Array or Vector type in Haskell to represent a 2D array.  What have you tried and what are your problems?  Be specific.

Comment: i would like through the line to determine the path to the @ symbol

Comment: @Boyd Stephen Smith Jr. i would like to go through the line to search the way  reach to the @ symbole. if there is no way, i would like to display the way i tried to used.

Comment: @user3841581 Do something like an A* path finding algorithm

Comment: Are you asking what algorithm to use?  You seem to have already done this in Java; you can use the same algorithm in Haskell.  If you are having trouble translating your Java to Haskell, you should be more specific.

Comment: yes i have the algo. here is the algo:Dfs(i,j)
{
 if(arr[i][j+1] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size){
  Dfs(i,j+1) 
 }else if(arr[i][j+1] == "@"){
  
 }
 
 if(arr[i][j-1] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size){
  Dfs(i,j-1) 
 }else if(arr[i][j-1] == "@"){
  

 if(arr[i+1][j] == "-" && i >=0 && i<=row.size && j>=0  && j<=column.size){
  Dfs(i+1,j) 
 }else if(arr[i+1][j] == "@"){
  
 }   . how can i translate this into haskell

Comment: @user3841581 Could you please put that into your question?  It's really hard to see the code in a comment.

Comment: @bheklilr i have just done that.

Comment: @user3841581 Your java code doesn't seem to do anything.  It'll traverse the structure, but it doesn't modify the array or return anything, so I don't know what specifically about that algorithm you want to replicate.

Comment: it is an algorithm that i thought i could use. it look for the @ sign, gong right, left and down. that is the first step. if i can find the @ sign, then the next step will be to replace the path use to reach the @ with +. however if you have a better approach, to tacle this problem, can you please share it with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways of making 2D arrays in Haskell, here is a somewhat laborious example of reading the chars into a Data.Array array, and then moving things about with the so-called `state monad`:

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

main = do str <- getContents -- accepts string from stdin
          let array = mkThingArray str -- we parse the string
              limits = snd (bounds array) -- we remember (height,width)
              initialState = ((0::Int,-1::Int),limits,array)
          ((position,(h,w),a)) <- execStateT findpath initialState
          let chars = elems $ fmap toChar a
          putStrLn ""
          putStrLn $ splitText (w+1) chars

parseArray str = listArray ((0,0),(height-1, width-1)) total where 
    rawlines = lines str
    ls       = filter (not . null) rawlines
    lens     = map length ls
    height   = length ls 
    width    = minimum lens 
    proper   = map (take width) ls
    total    = concat proper              

data Thing = Open | Closed | Home | Taken deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
toThing c = case c of '-' -> Open; '#' -> Closed; '@' -> Home;
                      '+' -> Taken; _ -> error "No such Thing"
toChar c = case c of Open -> '-'; Closed -> '#'; 
                     Home -> '@'; Taken -> '+'

mkThingArray str = fmap toThing (parseArray str)
```

And continuing with an absurdly primitive 'logic' of state change:

```
-- we begin with moveright, which may then pass on to movedown 
-- and so on perhaps in a more sophisticated case
findpath = moveright 
  where
  moveright = do ((n,m), (bound1,bound2), arr) <- get
                 if m < bound2 
                 then case arr ! (n,m+1) of
                   Open   -> do liftIO (putStrLn "moved right")
                                put ((n,m+1), (bound1,bound2), arr // [((n,m+1),Taken)])
                                moveright
                   Closed -> movedown
                   Home   -> return ()
                   Taken  -> movedown
                 else movedown

  movedown = do ((n,m), (bound1,bound2), arr) <- get
                if n < bound1 
                then case arr ! (n+1,m) of
                   Open   -> do liftIO (putStrLn "moved down")
                                put ((n+1,m), (bound1,bound2), arr // [((n+1,m),Taken)])
                                moveright
                   Closed -> moveright
                   Home   -> return ()
                   Taken  -> moveright
                else moveright    

splitText n str = unlines $ split n [] str 
   where split n xss []  = xss
         split n xss str = let (a,b) = splitAt n str
                           in if not (null a) 
                                then split n (xss ++ [a]) b
                                else xss
```

which, in this happy case, gives output like this

```
{-
$ pbpaste | ./arrayparse 
moved right
moved right
moved right
moved down
moved right
moved right
moved down
moved right
moved right
moved right
moved right
moved right
moved right
moved right

+++#--###----
-#+++#----##-
----++++++++@
-}
```

The logic will have to be more sophisticated, with `moveleft` and `moveup`, etc., etc. but this is supposed to give the idea, or an idea.

Edit: Here is a version that doesn't use an intermediate type and doesn't throw any IO into the state machine.  It should be more usable in ghci, so you can tear it apart more easily:

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict

main = do str <- readFile "input.txt"
          ((pos,(h,w),endarray)) <- execStateT findpath 
                                               (mkInitialState str)
          putStrLn $ prettyArray endarray

-- the following are just synonyms, nothing is happening:
type Pos = (Int, Int)      -- Our positions are in 2 dimensions
type Arr = Array Pos Char  -- Characters occupy these positions
type ArrState = (Pos, Pos, Arr) -- We will be tracking not just 
                                --  an array of Chars but a 
                                --  current position and the total size
parseArray :: String -> Arr
parseArray str = listArray ((1,1),(height, width)) (concat cropped) where 
    ls       = filter (not . null) (lines str)
    width    = minimum (map length ls)     
    height   = length ls            
    cropped  = map (take width) ls -- the map is cropped to shortest line

prettyArray :: Arr -> String
prettyArray arr = split [] (elems arr)
  where (ab,(h,w)) = bounds arr 
        split xss []  = unlines xss 
        split xss str = let (a,b) = splitAt w str
                        in if null a then unlines xss else split (xss ++ [a]) b

mkInitialState :: String -> ArrState
mkInitialState str = ((1::Int,0::Int), limits, array)
 where array = parseArray str      -- we parse the string
       limits = snd (bounds array) -- we remember (height,width)
        -- since we don't resize, tracking this could be avoided

makeStep :: Arr -> Pos -> Arr   
makeStep arr (n, m) = arr // [((n,m),'+')]  -- this is crude

moveRight, moveDown, findpath :: Monad m => StateT ArrState m ()
moveRight = do ((n,m),bounds,arr) <- get
               put ((n,m+1), bounds, makeStep arr (n,m+1))
moveDown = do ((n,m),bounds,arr) <- get
              put ((n+1,m), bounds, makeStep arr (n+1,m))
findpath = tryRight  
  where -- good luck for most paths ...
  tryRight  = do ((n,m), (_,bound2), arr) <- get
                 if m < bound2 
                 then case arr ! (n,m+1) of
                   '@' -> return ()
                   '-' -> do moveRight
                             tryRight 
                   _   -> tryDown 
                 else tryDown 

  tryDown  = do ((n,m), (bound1,_), arr) <- get
                if n < bound1 
                then case arr ! (n+1,m) of
                   '@'   -> return ()
                   '-'   -> do moveDown
                               tryRight 
                   _  -> tryRight 
                else tryRight     

runInput :: String -> String
runInput str = prettyArray endarray
 where ((position,(h,w),endarray)) = execState findpath (mkInitialState str)
 -- If I wanted to include IO things in the state machine,
 -- I would have to use execStateT not execState, which presupposes purity
test :: String -> IO ()
test str = putStrLn (runInput str)

t1 = unlines ["---#--###----" 
             , ""
             , "-#---#----##-"
             , ""
             , "------------@"
             ] :: String
--
t2 = unlines ["---#--###----"
             ,""
             ,"---#-#----##-"
             ,""
             ,"------------@"
             ] :: String
```

Comment: thank you;can you please edit your code and include comment? when i try to run and i call the find path function, it show me an error: No instance for (Show
                       (StateT ((Int, Int), (Int, Int), Array (Int, Int) Thing) IO ()))
      arising from a use of `print'

Comment: also when i cal the main function, it starts loading array module and it never stops

Comment: Change the first line of `main` from `str <- getContents` to `str <- readFile "input.txt"` . The current form is expecting the document to come to it from `stdin`, which was just to simplify things. I will think how to make `findpath` more usable inside ghci.

Comment: I appended a modified version that may be simpler to comprehend and fiddle with in `ghci`. Something like `runInput this_str` will be more usable in `ghci`, where `this_str` is a string representing an initial maze. `findpath` is a "state machine" and could hardly be printed just by itself in `ghci` .  Keep in mind that this is *very* simple-minded, there are much much faster array types around, for example, but this one is amazingly convenient.  To emulate the Java, we would use a mutable array type, which is pointless here.

Comment: Thank you, it does work, however, when i compile it, when i call the main function, it does respond  it is on a kind of listening mode. also can you please exlain what is happening in after test str .....?

Comment: Is there a file called "index.txt" in the same directory? -- `main` is presupposing this. As for `test`: when you type `test t1` in ghci, it parses the string `t1` runs the state machine on it, and prints the final array in string form. So you would apply `test` to any actual string that represents an initial state, and you will see the text marked with the path.  This function may diverge on some inputs; I was leaving it to you to improve the `findpath` function.

Comment: Oh, there was a little error in the module attached at the end; I think it should compile properly, if it hadn't.  It occurs to me that the question about "listening mode" may refer to the module described in the main body of the text, which uses `getContents`. It is indeed in listening mode ... You can use it by getting the file into stdin, e.g. `cat file.txt | ./myhaskellexecutable` or whatever.  Or just replace `getContents` as I do in the other module appended.

Comment: well in my main i have a input file wih i rename to to input.txt but when i try to compile it it give me this: Not in scope: `morphInput'

Comment: Yeah, change to word `morphInput` to `runInput` in the line that defines `test`. I corrected this in the file pasted at the end.

Comment: i did that and now when i call the main function, it is just handing just like in the sleep mode as i mentioned earlier

Comment: This is hard to follow. What happens if you take the module appended at the end there, open it in ghci, and type `test t1` ?

Comment: @Arthur why in your second example do you change the initial position from (0,-1) to (1,0)? I was toying with the second example but offsets and starting points seemed odd, using first one now (works nicely) but was curious.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on the way you want to use your 2D array.

If you only care about sequential use, a simple list of lists (basically `[[Char]]`) may be fine.

If you care about efficient getting to particular random coordinates, I can imagine that an `IntList IntList Char` could work for you; it's almost like list of lists, but individual cells can be much more efficiently updated, and it gives cheap random access for pathfinding.

Possibly a [zipper](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/195734/11732)-like structure would suit you best. I can't (so far) imagine a nice structure of this type that gives you both cheap (O(1) per neighbor cell) navigation for pathfinding *and* cheap updates.

Also, you could use a mutable map via `Monad.Control.State` e.g. by keeping a `Data.Array` in it, but you will have to lift all your logic into this monad (which would complicate passing copies of the map around, when you need it).

Comment: can you please give me a simple example?